# What is the difference between OnFirstUIBefore OnMaintUIBefore and OnUpdateUIBefore

Tags: windows-installer, installshield

All, For these event. What I understand would looks like below.

```cpp
  if ( bMaintenanceMode ) then
    OnMaintUIBefore();
  else
    OnFirstUIBefore();
  endif;
```

if the current setup is maintenance mode . then trigger the `OnMaintUIBefore` event. But I can't understand the `OnUpdateUIBefore` event. Could someone please  help to review my questions below.

1. When would `OnUpdateUIBefore` event be triggered?
2. `Maintenance` is not `Update` ?
3. Uninstall is `Maintenance` or `Update`?

Comment: I have exactly the same question(s).  Running a minor-version update with an InstallScript installer, it seems that my `OnUpdateUIBefore` handler is not called: I sense that `OnMaintUIBefore` is counterintuitively where I should relocate my custom logic; but since maintenance mode seems to be...everything, I am unclear how to condition the custom logic to only run in the update scenario I expect.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't figure it out too..

Comment: Speaking to one piece of the puzzle at least, it turned out that `OnUpdateUIBefore` _was_ being called when I ran my minor-version update.

Comment: What is the IS version you have ? I was using IS2010.

Comment: InstallShield 2012 Spring - Professional Edition (Version 19, Service Pack 1)

Answer (score 0):

Ad point 3: Uninstall is uninstall, the setup is called with option `/uninst`.